# Is there a way to integrate zephyr with github?

Tags: jira-zephyr

I am going through the zephyr for jira cloud plugin and would like to know if there is any plugin available or any way through witch we can integrate zephyr with github?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is a feature request. Our Product Management team has been made aware of this feature request. They will review the same for consideration. We appreciate your valuable feedback in making Zephyr for jira cloud better.

Thanks
Pooja

Comment: 6 years past. Any news?